# Remove Click Event only in a specific browser view

Tags: javascript, click, removeeventlistener

I have a Toggle displaying content. I am trying to remove its click event in larger than 600px of browser view. That means the Toggle click functionality should not work in larger view of 600px. Following is the code i used.

HTML:

```
<div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
<div class="content">This is the Toggle Displaying content</div>
```

```
let trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
let content = document.querySelector(".content");

mobilefunction=(el)=>{
let cs = window.getComputedStyle(el).display;
if(cs==="none") {el.style.display="block"}
else {el.style.display="none";}
}

responsivemenu=()=> {
let windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
if(windowwidth < 500) {
    trigger.addEventListener("click", ()=>{mobilefunction(content)});
}
else {
    trigger.removeEventListener("click", ()=>{mobilefunction(content)});
}
}

window.addEventListener("resize", responsivemenu );
responsivemenu();
```

I am trying to make Click event enable only in mobile and remove it for desktop. Seeking for experts help on this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to not add/remove the eventlistener but just check inside the listener callback.
By doing this you can drop all the resize handler stuff as the width is validated the second you click.

```js
let trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
let content = document.querySelector(".content");

mobilefunction = () => {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 500) {
    return;
  }

  let cs = window.getComputedStyle(content).display;
  if (cs === "none") {
    content.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    content.style.display = "none";
  }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", mobilefunction);
```

```html
<div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
<div class="content">This is the Toggle Displaying content</div>
```

Comment: Schoner, Hi Fabian, Wonderfull! Thanks for your great help. Could you help me on understanding the logic you used here. Actually my understanding was nothing will work after 'return' statement. But here everything work like a charm. Hopes here you used a JS core logic. If you can educate me on the logic. That would be helpfull.

Comment: Sure! `return;` makes the function return an empty value which makes the function stop right there, return an empty value and skip the rest of the function. BUT that return statement is encapsulated inside the if clause (i added proper brakets in my code to make that clearer) so the `return;` statement is only reached if the condition `window.innerWidth >= 500` evaluates to true. In case it doesnt, the `return;` statement is NOT executed and the function keeps on running (which in this case means hiding/showing the `content` element).

Comment: Hi Fabian, Its really excellent your explanation and the meeting with you is the most valuable thing. Because for a long time I was using jQuery and now due to the Web is moving with JavaScript majority, I was also moving with it. Now i only use Vanilla JS instead of jQuery and I got better Google PSI score and User experience. Please expect more doubt from me as i am really looking for an expert like you to consult for my Works.